# Using 'this' in a JavaScript class's function that is called with .map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following class:

```
class RegisterUser {
  constructor(username, password, ispublic){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.ispublic = ispublic;
    this.identity = crypto.signKey();
    this.preKeys = [];
    if (ispublic){
      this.preKeys = crypto.getPreKeys(10);
    }
  }
  get data(){
    return {
      identity_key: this.identity.publicKey,
      username: this.username,
      usernameSignature: this.usernameSignature,
      signedPreKeys: this.signedPreKeys,
      ispublic: this.ispublic
    }
  }
  get usernameSignature(){
    return this.identity.sign(buf(this.username, 'utf8'));
  }
  signPreKey(key){
    var publicKey = key.publicKey;
    var signature = this.identity.sign(pub);
    return {
      publicKey: publicKey,
      signature: signature
    }
  }
  get signedPreKeys(){
    var signFunc = this.signPreKey;
    return this.preKeys ? this.preKeys.map(signFunc) : null;
  }
  get encryptedIdentity(){
    var cipher = ncrypto.createCipher('aes192', this.password);
    var encrypted = new Buffer(cipher.update(this.identity.secretKey));
    return Buffer.concat([encrypted, new Buffer(cipher.final())]);
  }
}
```

When `.data()` is called on a newly instantiated instance of this class, I get:

> Cannot read property 'identity' of undefined" in the signPreKey function.

Is there a way to use `.map` in a way that will not replace `this`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), which forces the context of the function.

```
  get signedPreKeys(){
    var signFunc = this.signPreKey.bind(this);
    return this.preKeys ? this.preKeys.map(signFunc) : null;
  }
```

Alternately, pass `this` as the second argument to [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
  get signedPreKeys(){
    var signFunc = this.signPreKey;
    return this.preKeys ? this.preKeys.map(signFunc, this) : null;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the array `map` method takes a second argument exactly for this purpose.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> ```
> var new_array = arr.map(callback[, thisArg])
> ```

Just pass the `thisArg` you want as the second argument like so:

```
return this.preKeys ? this.preKeys.map(signFunc, this) : null;
```